# How to prove determinant of matrices identity?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I have the following linear algebra practice question:

> Let $A, B, C, D$ be four $n \times n$ matrices. Show that if $D$ is invertible and $CD = DC$, then
> $$\det\begin{pmatrix} A & B \\ C & D \end{pmatrix} =  \det(AD − BC).$$

I'm a bit confused about how to even approach this question since I'm taking the determinant of a matrix with matrix entries. My understanding was that the determinant was an operator on real number entries of a matrix, not matrices themselves. How can I then begin proving this if the operator isn't defined for matrices, or am I missing something?

Comment: The idea is that your left hand side matrix is also a matrix with real entries: it is a $2n$ by $2n$ matrix, where the top left quarter has the same entries as $A$, the top right quarter the same entries as $B$, etc. In particular, you can take the determinant of that matrix.

Comment: @ENV This matrix is a [block matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix). It is not true that the matrix has matrices as entries. However, it is often possible to get the right answers by "pretending" that these submatrices are each an entry of the matrix, particularly in matrix multiplication.

Comment: Oh ok, that makes sense. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With block matrix multiplication, we have
$$
\pmatrix{I & 0\\0 & D^{-1}}\pmatrix{A&B\\C&D} = \pmatrix{A & B\\ D^{-1}C & I}\\
\pmatrix{A & B \\D^{-1}C & I} \pmatrix{I&0\\-D^{-1}C & I} = \pmatrix{A - BD^{-1}C & B\\ 0 & I}
$$
That is, we have
$$
\pmatrix{I & 0\\0 & D^{-1}}\pmatrix{A&B\\C&D}\pmatrix{I&0\\-D^{-1}C & I} = 
\pmatrix{A - BD^{-1}C & B\\ 0 & I}.
$$
Now, verify that
$$
\det \pmatrix{I & 0\\0 & D^{-1}} = \det(D^{-1}) = \det(D)^{-1}, \\
\det \pmatrix{I & 0\\-D^{-1}C & I} = 1,\\
\det\pmatrix{A - BD^{-1}C & B\\ 0 & I} = \det(A - BD^{-1}C).
$$
So, taking the determinant on both sides and rearranging yields
$$
\det \pmatrix{A & B\\C & D} = \det(A - BD^{-1}C)\det(D).
$$
Now, note that the fact that $CD = DC$ implies that $CD^{-1} = D^{-1}C$. Thus, we can rewrite
$$
\det(A - BD^{-1}C)\det(D) = \\
\det(A - BCD^{-1})\det(D) = \\
\det([A - BCD^{-1}]D) = \\
\det(AD - BC).
$$